# Duplicate files using java timestamp naming

Tags: java, file, audio, timestamp

I have an application that merges two audio files into a single one.
My problem is, that when I run the application, sometimes (haven't been able to find out exactly when) I get the same file duplicated with two different names. When the output should be just 1 file

Here's the code I'm using to name the files:

```
AudioInputStream    audioInputStream = null;
    audioInputStream = new MixingFloatAudioInputStream(audioFormat, audioInputStreamList);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String      strOutputFilename = timeStamp + "-" + tel +".wav";
    System.out.println("Llamadas/" + strOutputFilename);
    File    outputFile = new File("Llamadas/" + strOutputFilename);
try
    {
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outputFile);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It doesn't throws any kind of error, I just get the duplicates with a difference on their names of 1 second on their tampstamp part.

ie:

```
20130910134003-097496427.wav
20130910134004-097496427.wav
```

Any idea of the reason or another method to get always the right timestamp?

Comment: How the file is written? Give code just initialize the output file, but not saved to disk.

Comment: @Kowser Already added the writting code. The output is the desired one if I use some other naming method.